# Authentication error using Rails - Devise and AngularJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, angularjs

I am using Devise for user authentication in a Rails application. I tried to use AngularJS instead of the default rails scaffolding in an application. The problem is that when I add the before_filter :authenticate_user! in the controller then AngularJS calls to update/save and delete a resource does not work saying Unauthorized Access (401). Here is some of the code:

The resource:

```
@app.factory "employeesDB", ($resource) ->
  $resource("/employees/:id", {id: "@id"}, {update: {method: "PUT"}},
    {destroy: {method: "DELETE"}}
  )
```

The save action:

```
  $scope.saveEmpl = ->
    $scope.em = new Object if !$scope.em
    employeesDB.save({}, $scope.em, (resource) ->
      $scope.employees.push(resource)
    , (response) ->
      console.log("Failed")
    )
```

$scope.em is the object containing the data for the record and it is bind to angular using ng-model.

Everything works perfect if I remove the before_filter :authenticate_user! from the controller

```
class EmployeesController < ApplicationController
  #before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

The problem occurs only when I try to save/update/delete the record, just reading it works OK.

Any ideas?? Are there any specific guidlines I should follow when using Angular and Devise?
I am newbie to rails and angularJS so a detailed explanation will be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried passing `withCredentials` parameter to your $httpProvider defaults? `app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;}]);`?

Comment: Added the following, but unfortunately it didn't work. I get the same problem.@app = angular.module("Mathra", ["ngResource"]).config(['$httpProvider', ($httpProvider) ->
  $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true
  ])

Answer (score 10):

You can add this to your `app.js`:

```
myApp.config([
  "$httpProvider", function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] = angular.element('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');
  }
]);
```

Which add CSRF token to all Angular requests.

**EDIT:** Now jQuery independent (use [jqLite](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element)).

Answer (score 6):

I found out that I had to use the CSRF token.

http://ngmodules.org/modules/ng-rails-csrf